# War es das? - Definition clarity

Tags: phrase

I am finding conflicting information regarding this phrase. I'm constructing some flash cards, but I'm stuck on this entry for my deck. An information would be wonderful.

One place I see the literal translation:

> War es das? - Was it that/this?

Other places (mainly spoken dialog), I see it as this:

> War es das? - Are we done?
>
> War es das jetzt? - Are we done yet?

Answer (score 5):

"War es das?" can mean both, depending on context and emphasis.

"War es das jetzt?" is obviously "Are we done yet?".

Actually "War es das?" means "Was it that?" but it is often used as "Was it (the stuff that was happening) that (the stuff that had to happen)"?